# Как указать для проверки в isinstance() тип объекта "function"?

Tags: python, функции, типы

Возникла необходимость использовать `isinstance()`  для функции. Но не все оказалось просто.

```
def foo():
    ...

  
def bar(d):
    return d    

isinstance(foo, type(bar))
```

Работает правильно и возвращает `True`.  Однако зарезервированного слова для `function` нет.  И при попытке написать что то типа

```
isinstance(foo, function)
```

Мы получаем ошибку, несмотря на то, что

```
type(bar)  

function
```

Хотя я и привел выше работающий вариант кода, я воспринимаю его как "костыль".  Как говорят гранды - "Должен быть способ лучше!" )

Comment: должна ли ваша проверка давать `True` на встроенные методы (`open`, к примему) ?

Comment: Да, например на int. float и другие конструкторы типов

Comment: @n1tr0xs  если хочешь - давай ответ я поставлю отметку. )

Comment: мой ответ строился на том же, который вы обнаружили сами. так что...

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function) нашел ответ.

```
from types import BuiltinFunctionType, BuiltinMethodType,  FunctionType, MethodType, LambdaType
from functools import partial

def is_function(obj):
  return isinstance(obj, (BuiltinFunctionType, 
BuiltinMethodType,  FunctionType, MethodType, LambdaType, partial))

#-------------------------------------------------

def my_func():
  pass

def add_both(x, y):
  return x + y

class a:
  def b(self):
    pass

check = [

is_function(lambda x: x + x),
is_function(my_func),
is_function(a.b),
is_function(partial),
is_function(partial(add_both, 2))

]

print(check)
>>> [True, True, True, False, True]
```

Вот уж не знал, что в Python столько **разных** типов для того, что я ощущал под одним словом "функция".